# SQLite with Foreign Key + Models Android Studio CRUD

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, crud

**Sorry with my English**

I'll build a simple example:

---

**Table T_User**

```
id_user integer primary key autoincrement,

email_user text not null,

pass_user text not null,

id_person integer foreign key(id_person) references T_Person(id_person)
```

---

**Table T_Person**

```
id_person integer primary key autoincrement,

name_person text not null,

cel_person text not null
```

---

**Android Studio:**

**User.java**

```
public static final String TAG = User.class.getSimpleName();
```

**1) Here i need to put the same name of the table ?**

```
public static final String TABLE = "T_User";
```

**2) Here i need to put all of columns of my table? like "id_user"**

```
public static final int KEY_ID_USER = "id_user";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL_USER = "email_user";
public static final String KEY_PASS_USER= "pass_user";
public static final int KEY_ID_PERSON = "id_person";

private int id;
private String email;
private String pass;
private Person person;
//constructor
//getters & setters
```

**UserRepo.java**

```
    public static String createTable(){
        return "CREATE TABLE " + User.TABLE  + "("
                + User.KEY_ID_USER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + User.KEY_EMAIL_USER + " TEXT,"
                + User.KEY_PASS_USER + " TEXT,"
                + User.KEY_ID_PERSON  + " INTEGER)";
    }
    public void insert(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
```

**3) I dont need this line right? (because of autoincrement)**

```
        values.put(User.KEY_ID_USER, user.getId());


        values.put(User.KEY_EMAIL_USER, user.getEmail());
        values.put(User.KEY_PASS_USER, user.getPass());
```

**4) Here is like that to i get the id from person?**

```
        values.put(User.KEY_ID_PERSON , user.person.getId());


        db.insert(User.TABLE, null, values);
        DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
    }
```

**5) How can i do Update and Select**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example based upon your design with update and select methods.

This consists of 2 java classes, and invoking activity **MainActivity.java** and a subclass of the SQLiteOpenHelper class, often called the DBHelper, hence it being **DBHelper.java**

#### DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_USER = "T_User";
    public static final String TB_PERSON = "T_Person";

    public static final String COl_USER_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_USER_EMAIL = "email_user";
    public static final String COL_USER_PASS = "pass_user";
    public static final String COl_USER_PERSON = "id_person";

    public static final String COL_PERSON_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_PERSON_NAME = "name_person";
    public static final String COL_PERSON_CEL = "cel_person";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB  = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtpersonsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_PERSON + "(" +
                COL_PERSON_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COl_PERSON_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                COL_PERSON_CEL + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
                ")";
        String crtusersql = "CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS " + TB_USER + "(" +
                COl_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COl_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + //perhaps make unique
                COL_USER_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COl_USER_PERSON + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TB_PERSON + "(" +
                COL_PERSON_ID +
                ")" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtpersonsql);
        db.execSQL(crtusersql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertPerson(String name, String cel) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_PERSON_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_PERSON_CEL,cel);
        return mDB.insert(TB_PERSON,null,cv);
    }

    public long insertUser(String email, String pass, long personid) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_USER_EMAIL,email);
        cv.put(COL_USER_PASS,pass);
        cv.put(COl_USER_PERSON,personid);
        return mDB.insert(TB_USER,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllPersons() {
        return mDB.query(TB_PERSON,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllUsers() {
        return mDB.query(TB_USER,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllPersonsAndTheReferencedUser() {
        String table = TB_PERSON +
                " JOIN " + TB_USER +
                " ON " + COl_USER_PERSON + "=" +
                TB_PERSON + "." + COL_PERSON_ID;
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                TB_PERSON + "." + COL_PERSON_ID + " AS " + TB_PERSON + "_" + COL_PERSON_ID,
                COl_PERSON_NAME,
                COL_PERSON_CEL,
                TB_USER + "." + COl_USER_ID + " AS " + TB_USER + "_" + COl_USER_ID,
                COl_USER_EMAIL,
                COL_USER_PASS
        };
        Log.d("GETALLPandU","Table (FROM) clause = " + table);
        return mDB.query(table,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public int changePersonsName(long personid, String newname) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_PERSON_NAME,newname);
        String whereclause = COL_PERSON_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(personid)};
        return mDB.update(TB_PERSON,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
    }

    public int changePersonsCel(long personid, String newcel) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_PERSON_CEL,newcel);
        String whereclause = COL_PERSON_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(personid)};
        return mDB.update(TB_PERSON,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
    }
}
```

- Method **insertPerson** is used to add a row to the **T_Person** table.
- Method **insertUser** is used to add a row to the **T_User** table, noting that the personid (the 3rd parameter) has to reference a Person.
- Method **getAllPersons** gets all the rows from the **T_Person** table.
- Method **getAllUsers** gets all the rows from the **T_User** table.
- Method **getAllPersonsAndTheReferencedUser** gets all the rows, according to the Foreign Keys/references, from the Person and User tables.
- Method **changePersonsName** allows the **name** of a Person to be updated according to the **id** of the person.
- Method **changePersonscel** allows the **cel** of a Person to be updated according to the **id** of the person.

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);

        // Delete all rows from both tables (if any)
        mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper.TB_USER,null,null);
        mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper.TB_PERSON,null,null);

        // Add some person rows
        mDBHlpr.insertPerson("Fred","0000-000-000"); // id will virtually certainly be 1
        mDBHlpr.insertPerson("Bert", "1111-111-111"); // id likely 2
        mDBHlpr.insertPerson("Mary","2222-222-222"); // id likely 3

        // Add some user rows
        mDBHlpr.insertUser("Fred@email.moc","Fred1234567890",1);
        mDBHlpr.insertUser("Bert@email.moc","Bert1234567890",2);
        mDBHlpr.insertUser("Mary@email.moc","Mary1234567890",3);

        //ooops add some unanticipated rows
        mDBHlpr.insertUser("whoever@email.moc","xxxx",3);
        mDBHlpr.insertUser("whoever@email.moc","xxxx",3);

        // Make some changes (updates)
        mDBHlpr.changePersonsCel(3,"6666-666-66");
        mDBHlpr.changePersonsName(3,"Marian");

        // get some data
        Cursor crs1 = mDBHlpr.getAllPersons();
        Cursor csr2 = mDBHlpr.getAllUsers();
        Cursor csr3 = mDBHlpr.getAllPersonsAndTheReferencedUser();

        // Output the retrieved data
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(crs1);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr2);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr3);

        // Close the Cursors (should always be done when finished with the Cursor)
        crs1.close();
        crs1.close();
        csr3.close();
    }
}
```

This invokes the methods in the DBHelper.

- First an instance of the DBHelper is instantiated (mDBHlpr).
- Next all rows (if any) are deleted from both tables (this is done to make the App's results consistent).
- Next some Persons and then users are added (including some unanticipated/unexpected users (***the result being that Person 3 is referenced by 3 users***)).
- Some changes are then made (Mary is changed to Marian, Mary's(nor Marian's) cel is changed from 2222-222-222 to 6666-666-66).
- All three of the selection methods (getAll....) are run and 3 Cursors are created.
- The Cursors are dumped (written to the log).
- The Cursors are closed.

### The 3 outputs are :-

#### The Person table (3 rows) :-

```
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@a98de41
09-01 21:48:52.535 1919-1919/so52115977.so52115977 I/System.out: 0 {
       _id=1
09-01 21:48:52.536 1919-1919/so52115977.so52115977 I/System.out:    name_person=Fred
       cel_person=0000-000-000
    }
    1 {
       _id=2
       name_person=Bert
       cel_person=1111-111-111
    }
    2 {
       _id=3
       name_person=Marian
       cel_person=6666-666-66
    }
<<<<<
```

#### The User table (5 rows)

```
    >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@e149fe6
    0 {
       _id=1
       email_user=Fred@email.moc
       pass_user=Fred1234567890
       id_person=1
    }
    1 {
       _id=2
       email_user=Bert@email.moc
       pass_user=Bert1234567890
       id_person=2
    }
    2 {
       _id=3
       email_user=Mary@email.moc
       pass_user=Mary1234567890
09-01 21:48:52.537 1919-1919/so52115977.so52115977 I/System.out:    id_person=3
    }
    3 {
       _id=4
       email_user=whoever@email.moc
       pass_user=xxxx
       id_person=3
    }
    4 {
       _id=5
       email_user=whoever@email.moc
       pass_user=xxxx
       id_person=3
    }
    <<<<<
```

#### The linked/referenced/joined (Foreign Keyed) Person/User tables (5 rows)

```
    >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9645927
    0 {
       T_Person__id=1
       name_person=Fred
       cel_person=0000-000-000
       T_User__id=1
       email_user=Fred@email.moc
       pass_user=Fred1234567890
    }
    1 {
       T_Person__id=2
       name_person=Bert
       cel_person=1111-111-111
       T_User__id=2
       email_user=Bert@email.moc
       pass_user=Bert1234567890
    }
    2 {
       T_Person__id=3
       name_person=Marian
       cel_person=6666-666-66
       T_User__id=3
       email_user=Mary@email.moc
       pass_user=Mary1234567890
    }
    3 {
       T_Person__id=3
       name_person=Marian
       cel_person=6666-666-66
       T_User__id=4
       email_user=whoever@email.moc
       pass_user=xxxx
    }
    4 {
       T_Person__id=3
09-01 21:48:52.538 1919-1919/so52115977.so52115977 I/System.out:    name_person=Marian
       cel_person=6666-666-66
       T_User__id=5
       email_user=whoever@email.moc
       pass_user=xxxx
    }
    <<<<<
```

---

-**NOTE** ***`AUTOINCREMENT`*** has not been used.

- It's not actually AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite that results in the generation of a unique normally incrementing number.
- Specifying `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is generally sufficient and does not incur the overheads of the rarely needed AUTOINCREMENT [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)
- In fact, unless WITHOUT ROWID is specified then an SQLite table has a special, normally hidden column, called **rowid**, which is a 64bit signed integer, that will initially be 1, then likely 2, etc. Coding `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` makes the column an alias of the **rowid** column (AUTOINCREMENT can only be coded if INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is coded).

Comment: oh my ***** god, its perfect, sorry for my late, thanks so much

Comment: @Leonardo could you please tick this as the answer.